# Swing windowStateChanged listener returns previous property values of components

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane, windowlistener, windowstate

I have a Swing application with a JSplitPane and I want to get the width of the JSplitPane as soon as the window is maximized or restored. But I can't seem to get the correct value, it always returns the previous width of the JSplitPane. Not the width after the window state is changed.

I know I have to validate using the `evt.getNewState()` for NORMAL and MAXIMIZED_BOTH but it doesn't matter here.

```
addWindowStateListener(new java.awt.event.WindowStateListener() {
    public void windowStateChanged(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
       System.out.println(jsp.getWidth());
    }
});
```

This prints out `1812` if restored and `1120` if maximized. I also tried this with a few other components and ended up with the same result. How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found my own solution for this problem by using [`addComponentListener()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addComponentListener-java.awt.event.ComponentListener-) and handling the `componentResized` event for the `JFrame`. All the sub-components are updated in this event, so I was able to get the new width and perform my task. Still not perfect but close enough. See [*How to Write a Component Listener*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) for more.